# Update image path in database using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my controller code.

```
function edit_hotel($id) {
            $hotel = $this->hotel_model->get_hotel($id);

            $data['title'] = 'Edit Hotel';

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('hotelname', 'Hotel Name', 'required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('hotellocation', 'Hotel Location', 'required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('hotelphone', 'Hotel Phone', 'required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('hotelimg', 'Hotel Image', 'required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('hotelabout', 'Hotel About', 'required|xss_clean');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === true)
                {

                $config['upload_path'] = './images/hotelimages';
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
     $config['max_size']    = '1000000';
     $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
     $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
     $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
    print_r($config);
    echo "<br>after config<br>";
     $this->load->library('upload', $config);
     $field_name = "hotelimg";
     if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($field_name))
            {
     $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                $this->load->view('admin/edit_hotel', $error);
                }
                else {
                $image_data = $this->upload->data();
                print_r($image_data);
                echo "<br>after image_data<br>";
                $data = array(
                    'hotelname'             => $this->input->post('hotelname'),
                    'hotellocation'     => $this->input->post('hotellocation'),
                    'hotelphone'            => $this->input->post('hotelphone'),
                    'hotelimg'      =>    $image_data['full_path'],
                    'hotelabout'            => $this->input->post('hotelabout')
                );





                    $this->hotel_model->update_hotel($id, $data);

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "<p>Hotel updated successfully.</p>");

                    redirect(base_url().'index.php/admin/hotel_controller/index');
                }

            }


            $data['hotel'] = $hotel;



            $this->load->view('admin/edit_hotel', $data);
        }
```

This is the model

**To get data from database in to edit form fields**

```
function get_hotel($id) {
        $this->db->select('id, hotelname, hotellocation, hotelphone,hotelimg,    
hotelabout');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->limit(5);
        $query = $this->db->get('hotel_content');

        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

**To update database**

```
public function update_hotel($id, $data)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('hotel_content', $data);
    }
```

This is View page

```
<?php $id = $hotel['id']; ?>
<?php echo form_open("admin/hotel_controller/edit_hotel/$id");?>
    <table width="700" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td width="234" align="right"> <div align="left">Hotel Name:: </div></td>
          <td width="454"><input type="text" name="hotelname" id="hotelname" value="<?php  
            echo $hotel['hotelname']; ?>" class="input_field"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="234" align="right"> <div align="left">Hotel Location: </div></td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="hotellocation" id="hotellocation" value="<?php  
            echo $hotel['hotellocation']; ?>" class="input_field"/><?php //echo form_input($hotellocation); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><div align="left">Hotel Phone:</div></td>
            <td><input  type="text" name="hotelphone" id="hotelphone" value="<?php 
            echo $hotel['hotelphone']; ?>" class="input_field"/><?php //echo form_input($hotelphone); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"><div align="left">Hotel Image:</div></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="hotelimg" id="hotelimg" size="33" value="<?php 
            echo $hotel['hotelimg']; ?>" /><?php //echo form_input($hotelimg); ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="hotelimg" id="hotelimg" value="<?php 
            echo $hotel['hotelimg']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><div align="left">Hotel About:</div></td>
            <td><textarea name="hotelabout" id="hotelabout" cols="34" rows="5"> <?php 
            echo $hotel['hotelabout']; ?></textarea><?php //echo form_textarea($hotelabout); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');?>
                <input type="button" name="btnBack" id="btnBack" value="Back" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/hotel_controller/index'" />          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

The code above doesnt perform any action for updating image path in database.
so can anyone help me by correcting it. Thanking You in Advance

so it display's image path is this way

`print_r($image_data)`:

```
Array (
[file_name] =>
[file_type] =>
[file_path] => ./images/hotelimages/(**name of the image should be here**)
[full_path] => ./images/hotelimages/(**name of the image should be here**)
[raw_name] =>
[orig_name] =>
[client_name] =>
[file_ext] =>
[file_size] =>
[is_image] =>
[image_width] =>
[image_height] =>
[image_type] =>
[image_size_str] =>
)
```

after image_data

`print_r($data)`:

```
Array (
[hotelname] => aditya Hotels
[hotellocation] => Hyderbad
[hotelphone] => 04056894236
[hotelimg] => ./images/hotelimages/(**name of the image should be here**)
[hotelabout] => Aditya Sarovar Premiere is a well known lodging destination among many international and local tourists. Aditya Sarovar Premiere offers some state of the art rooms and modern facilities at affordable prices. It also has a fully equipped gym and a swimming pool. Perfect abode for all business and leisure guests, Aditya Sarovar Premiere is a great place to stay when in Hyderabad.
)
```

Comment: Is the data not being updated or being updated partially?

Comment: it jst stores the image path like "images/hotelimages"  but no image name is been stroing in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of **form_open()** in the view, use **form_open_multipart()** to allow file upload.